# Passing variables once by reference and once by value with the same prototype

Tags: c++

I know there is a difference between passing by reference and by value.

I want to know if it is possible to send to a function a variable once by reference and once by value.

In my example, I have the following prototype, and the vector is once called by reference and once by value, but the problem is that I need to do twice the same function instead of having another way to do it without having the same code twice.

```
int floodFill(vector<vector<sf::RectangleShape>>**&** image, int sr, int sc, sf::Color newColor)
```

It would be helpful if there is a way of how to handle it.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever need both. Can't you construct a copy within the function from the reference passed in?

Comment: Why do you need a non-const reference in the first place? Why your function can change my vector of shapes?

Comment: The answer might be templates. I would really recommend showing a more complete and simple code example so please can understand.

Comment: You don't *call* "by reference" or "by value", that's just how the arguments are *passed*. How are you going to use this function you show? What problem do you have with it now? When you say "call by reference" what do you mean by that? When you say "call by value" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Once I need to change the vector, and once I need to return an int. You right I could. Yet I would be interested to know if there is a way, since I would have to do a copy every time I enter by reference or value, or still I could use a boolean as well. But...

Comment: You will probably get more useful help if you explain why you need to call this function twice and get different results. What does it actually do in each case?

Comment: Since the functions you need to call do two different things, my recommendation is that you have two different functions (and with different names). Possible common code could be shared through other functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can always wrap a function that takes a reference into something that does not modify the parameter:

```
 // function taking reference
 void foo(T& t);

 // function taking value
 void foo_non_modifying(T t) { return foo(t); }
```

However, I would rather suggest you to fix the function. If a function takes a non-const reference then it should do that only if it needs to modify the parameter. And if that is the case the function cannot do what it is supposed to do if it does not modify its parameter. If you want the same function to do two different things, then probably you rather want two functions.

PS: I somehow ignored the "with the same signature" part of the question. To be honest I doubt that this is something desirable for the reason already mentioned: If two functions are doing something substantially different then they should be two different functions not one.